# Electron node-Gyp Library not loaded: dylib

Tags: node.js, macos, electron, node-gyp, dylib

I have an electron project bundled with a native node module, static and dynamic libs.

When runs the packaged app on mac, I'm getting below error in the developer console. The native node module(addon.node) loads ok but not the dylibs.

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot open ./addon.node: Error: dlopen(./addon.node, 1): Library not loaded: Core.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/Camera/Documents/myapp/dist/mac/myapp.app/Contents/Frameworks/addon.node
  Reason: image not found
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:3)
    at n (main.js:1)
    at Module.<anonymous> (main.js:306)
    at n (main.js:1)
    at main.js:1
    at main.js:1
```

**binding.gyp**

```
    "targets": [{
        "target_name": "addon",
        ...
        
        'conditions': [
            ['OS=="mac"', {
                ...

                'library_dirs': [
                    "/usr/local/lib",
                    "'$(CORE_DIR)'/lib"
                ],
                "link_settings": {
                    "libraries": [
                        "-L'$(CORE_DIR)'/lib",
                    ],
                },
                'libraries': [
                    "-lCore"
                ],
                "copies":[{
                    'destination': './',
                    'files': [
                        "$(CORE_DIR)/lib/Core.dylib"
                    ]
                }],
                'xcode_settings': {
                    'GCC_ENABLE_CPP_RTTI': 'YES',
                    'GCC_ENABLE_CPP_EXCEPTIONS': 'YES',
                    'CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY': 'libc++',
                }
            }],
```

I have these static and dynamic libs in CORE_DIR/lib

```
Core.a
Core.dylib
```

**Works Ok when**

Run the app in the terminal by running the executable file inside the packaged app.
But Core.dylib should present in the same directory of the terminal current directory.

```
./dist/mac/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp
```

But how to get this work with double click run? I have copied the Core.dylib wherever possible inside the packaged app, but nothing worked.

Thanks

Comment: I was able to run the app by changing the addon.node library install name with install_name_tool.
install_name_tool -change Core.dylib @rpath/Core.dylib addon.node

Now need to figure out how to put this into binding.gyp

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem while moving a project from windows to a mac.

Just remove node_modules and reinstall again its worked for me